# How can i adjust the position of images according to border?

Tags: css, position

I have a image in the frame(border). I want to image suspend from right border.
My codes in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p95NE/)..

Shortly **border's margin**.

"R" is any picture..

First status:

```
---------
|      R|
|       |
|       |
---------
```

I want this..

```
---------
|     R |
|       |
|       |
---------
```

Comment: Please review:  https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Do you mean float:right?

Comment: What you're asking would make more sense if you posted a working example in a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For image container object set style

```
position:relative
```

Set image style

```
position:absolute;right:6px
```

Comment: But i have new problem.. http://jsfiddle.net/p95NE/2/ please look.. Where is the other images?

Comment: Append your images into divs. Position that divs to relative.

Comment: I'm waiting your answer.. What can i do? already i have four img elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p95NE/8/

If I understand what you're trying to do It will be much easier.

Comment: somehow I still don't understand.http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/Su7T7/1/ My solution in your last question should just do the same thing and it is much easier. May I ask you the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

```
img { display: inline-block; margin-right: 6px }
```

Comment: @YusufAliBozkır, then you're going to have to explain what you're doing with a lot more detail.  Ask a vague question and you'll get a vague answer.

Comment: @YusufAliBozkır, you should not be tagging your question with `margin`, if you don't want to use margins.

Answer (score 0):

put your image inside container like div tag and style as you want

```
div.imagecontainer{
float:left;
border:1px solid #000;
margin-right:6px;
}
```

it should do it